# Find property as TObject in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, rtti

I have two type of classes like this in **Delphi 7**:

```
  TPhone = Class(TPersistent)
  private
    FNumber: string;
  published
    property Number: string read FNumber write FNumber;
  end;

  TPerson = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FFirstName: string;
    FPhone: TPhone;
  public
    constructor Create;
  published
    property FirstName: string40 read FFirstName write FFirstName;
    property Phone: TPhone read FPhone write FPhone;
  end;
```

How can I find **Phone** property in **TPerson** by it's name and return it as a **TObject** ?

Maybe something like this:

```
  function FindPropByName(AObject: TObject; APropName: string): TObject;
```

**Note that Phone is subclass and no primitive type**

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way for instance:

```
uses
  TypInfo;

var
  Phone: TPhone;
  Person: TPerson;
begin
  ...
  if PropIsType(Person, 'Phone', tkClass) then
    Phone := GetObjectProp(Person, 'Phone') as TPhone;
  ...
end;
```